# GLSL ES 2.0 - Alternative for UBO?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl, glsles

From what I've read of the `invariant` keyword for GLSL ES 2.0, it sounds kind of like something which could be considered synonymous with the functionality provided by a uniform buffer object, in the sense that multiple shader programs can "share" the data provided for various inputs. What I'd like to know is whether or not this could be used as an alternative for a UBO in any way. Since OpenGL ES 2.0 appears to not provide support for UBOs, and if the `invariant` keyword can't act as an alternative, is it possible to obtain similar functionality, using extensions or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`invariant` has absolutely nothing to do with uniform buffers. `invariant` means that if two separate shaders have the same input values and use the same expression to compute the `invariant`-qualified output, then the output will be guaranteed to produce the *same value* in both shaders. Without that qualifier, such a guarantee does not exist.

`invariant` has nothing to do will sharing "the data provided for various inputs". `invariant` is about how the *output* is qualified and computed.

As for the rest of your question, no, OpenGL ES 2.0 has nothing similar to UBOs. You'll have to set different uniforms on different programs to the same value.